# System message (after form submit) not clearing

Tags: status-messages

Hope someone here can help me to find a solution to this. Here we go:

1. **Have created a custom theme for Drupal 8.6.9**
2. **In page--front.html.twig I created a custom region named "status_messages" which is hidden if messages_exists variable has nothing**

The twig of that region looks like this:

```
{% if messages_exists %} //this comes from my .theme file where I retrieve the messages
<div id="custom-status-messages">
  <div class="message">{{ page.status_messages }}</div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

3. **In my .theme file I retrieve the messages in a preprocess_page function like this:**

   ```
   $messenger = \Drupal::messenger();
   $variables['messages_exists'] = $messenger->all();
   ```
4. **In the drupal admin panel I added the message block into my custom "status_messages" region.**
5. **I created a form to be displayed in a contact specific url**

So after filling out the form and click on submit, the page is redirected to the frontpage and the message displays correctly ("thanks for your message...") but then when I refresh the page, the region is still displayed but without the message. I used dump to check message_exists variable and it is still displaying the message. Shouldn't it to clear the message after refresh?

Thanks and if I missing some info please let me know.

Comment: Probably the dump output is cached while the status message is not. Status messages are placeholdered and injected into the cached page right before delivered to the user having a session with a message and this message is cleared after displayed.

Comment: Hi @4k4, thanks for commenting. So do you have an idea how could I solve this issue? as I am really new to Drupal, still not sure how to manage it and as I said before, the message is not cleared after displayed.

Comment: There is no issue, it works as designed. You've said in the question after refresh the region is displayed without message, so it is cleared. You can't put a variable in a page which depends on the presence of messages, because when the page is rendered Drupal doesn't know if later before delivery a message will be injected.